# Display graph hierarchy in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, silverlight, sharepoint, graph

We have a Sharepoint 2010 site and need to display graph hierarchy for connected objects. The hierarchy should be in a form of tree structure, but it can have cycles.

It will be a web part and currently I'm thinking of two approaches for rendering the graph: use Javascript library (js-graph http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/) or write  Silverlight web part (using quickgraph http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/). But I'm not familiar with Silverlight very much.

What will be a better approach here? Or both approaches are equal? Or there is a third one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It purely depends upon your requirements and development skills each has its pros and cons. 
so go for the one in which you are good. in your case i assume its JavaScript.

even their are third party controls provided by companies like Dundas which sell webpart suites which can solve your problems more easily but again you have to pay money for it.